# Does SQL Server for Linux support Application Consistent Backups

Tags: sql-server

We are looking to migrate from SQL Server 2k16 on Windows to SQL Server 2k17 on Linux.

Currently using DPM for our backup solution and looking it replace it with EC2 Snapshots.

On SQL Server for Windows, we could use VSS to get an Application-Consistent Snapshot.  I can't see any such support for the equivalent on Linux.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get Application-Consistent Snapshots on Linux?

Comment: Currently, in SQL17 there is no VSS integration.